# Itinerating picture editting in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Lately I've been trying to learn Python through a handson approach (I find it much more fun, although not as productive).

On this particular code I was trying to make a program to mass generate certificates.
Been cracking my head trying to solve this issue, the code keeps overwriting the old pictures and saving them again instead of getting a clean one from the base variable.

I tried moving the `base = Image.open("generico/Certificado.png")` into the `criacao(nome)` function, but then I get told that "base" hasn't been defined.

```
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
NameError: name 'base' is not defined
```

Help would be much appreciated!

```
import zlib, datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw


curso = input("Course: ")
inicio = input("Date of start (DD/MM): ")
fim = input("Date ended (formato DD/MM/AAAA): ")
horas = input ("Total hours spent: ")
professor = input("Professor: ")
quantos = int(input("Number of students: "))
contador = int(0)


base = Image.open("generico/Certificado.png")
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 50)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)


def criacao(nome):
    nome_arquivo = str(datetime.date.today()) + " " + nome[0].upper() + nome[1:len(nome)].lower() + " " + curso
    draw.text((750,1065), nome.upper(), font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((750,1414), curso.upper(), font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1220,1625), inicio, font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1500,1625), fim, font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1540,1750), horas + ".", font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1740,2130), str(datetime.date.today()), font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1550,2680), professor, font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    base.save("Criado/" + nome_arquivo + ".png")


while contador < quantos:
    criacao(input("Student's name: "))
    contador += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you need to move the `draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)` line in addition to the line that defines `base`. Your current error has to do with that line not being able to see `base` and it appears to be the means you're manipulating the image data anyway, so it makes sense.

Try this:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 50)

def criacao(nome):
    base = Image.open("generico/Certificado.png")     # move this line from above
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)                       # this one too

    nome_arquivo = str(datetime.date.today()) + " " + nome[0].upper() + nome[1:len(nome)].lower() + " " + curso
    draw.text((750,1065), nome.upper(), font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((750,1414), curso.upper(), font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1220,1625), inicio, font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1500,1625), fim, font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1540,1750), horas + ".", font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1740,2130), str(datetime.date.today()), font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    draw.text((1550,2680), professor, font=font, fill=(0,0,0,0))
    base.save("Criado/" + nome_arquivo + ".png")
```